# method in class returns NaN

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have a class Product with method buyProduct() accepting value (typeof NUMBER !) and return price of the product. I calculate it and it should return number but executed method returns NaN. where should I convert value that I put as an argument in buyProduct() method ? Thanks in advance

```js
class Product {
  /**
   *
   * @param {string} name
   * @param {number} price
   * @param {string} currency
   * @param {number} quantity
   */
  constructor(name, price, currency, quantity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  set name(name) {
    if (typeof name !== "string") {
      throw TypeError("value should be a string");
    } else {
      this._name = name;
    }
  }
  get price() {
    return this._price;
  }
  set price(price) {
    if (typeof price !== "number") {
      throw TypeError("value should be a number");
    } else {
      this._price = price;
    }
  }
  get currency() {
    return this._currency;
  }
  set currency(currency) {
    if (typeof currency !== "string") {
      throw TypeError("value should be a string");
    } else {
      this._currency = currency;
    }
  }
  get quantity() {
    return this._quantity;
  }
  set quantity(quantity) {
    if (typeof quantity !== "number") {
      throw TypeError("value should be a number");
    } else {
      this._quantity = quantity;
    }
  }


  buyProduct(value) {
    if (typeof value !== "number") {
      throw TypeError("value should be a number");
    } else {
      return (this._quantity - value) * this._price;
    }
  }
}

try {
  const product1 = new Product("laptop", 2000, "$", 10);
  const resultBuyProduct = product1.buyProduct(2);
  console.log(resultBuyProduct);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```

Comment: You never set `this.value`. That should just be `value`.